# Do opengl functions cause main thread to freeze?

Tags: opengl, rendering

So when you call  opengl functions, like glDraw or gLBufferData, does it cause the thread of the program to stop and wait for GL to finish the calls?

If not, then how does GL handle calling important functions like glDraw, and then immediately afterwards having a setting changed that affects the draw calls?

Comment: Yes they would generally be blocking functions, im not sure as i've not done it before but i assume that it would be run on a loop and updated only as needed to keep the framerate up.

Comment: @MattPsyK: OpenGL functions that don't introduce a synchronization point don't block.

Comment: My bad, assumptions were made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they (mostly) do not. The majority of GL functions are buffered when used and actually executed later. This means that you cannot think of the CPU and the GPU as two processors working together at the same time. Usually, the CPU executes a bunch of GL functions that get buffered and, as soon as they are delivered to the GPU, this one executes them. This means that you cannot reliably control how much time it took for a specific GL function to execute by just comparing the time before and after it's execution.

If you want to do that, you need to first run a glFinish() so it will actually wait for all previously buffered GL calls to execute, and then you can start counting, execute the calls that you want to benchmark, call glFinish again to make sure these calls executed as well, and then finish the benchmark.

On the other hand, I said "mostly". This is because reading functions will actually NEED to synchronize with the GPU to show real results and so, in this case, they DO wait and freeze the main thread.

edit: I think the explanation itself answers the question you asked second, but just in case: the fact that all calls are buffered make it possible for a draw to complete first, and then change a setting afterwards for succesive calls

Answer (score 1):

It strictly depends on the OpenGL call in question and the OpenGL state. When you make OpenGL calls, the implementation first queues them up internally and then executes them asynchronously to the calling program's execution. One important concept of OpenGL are synchronization points. Those are operations in the work queue that require the OpenGL call to block until certain conditions are met.

OpenGL objects (textures, buffer objects, etc.) are purely abstract and by specification the handle of an object in the client program always to the data, the object has at calling time of OpenGL functions that refer to this object. So take for example this sequence:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);

glTexImage2D(..., image_1);
draw_textured_quad();

glTexImage2D(..., image_2);
draw_textured_quad();
```

The first `draw_textured_quad` may return even long before anything has been drawn. However by making the calls OpenGL creates an internal reference to the data currently hold by the texture. So when glTexImage2D is called a second time, which may happen before the first quad was drawn, OpenGL must internally create a secondary texture object that's to become texture `texID` and to be used by the second calls of `draw_textured_quad`. If `glTexSubImage2D` was called, it would even have to make a modified copy of it.

OpenGL calls will only block, if the result of the call modifies client side memory and depends of data generated by previous OpenGL calls. In other words, when doing OpenGL calls, the OpenGL implementation internally generates a dependency tree to keep track of what depends on what. And when a synchronization point must block it will at least block until all dependencies are met.