# At what point does vsync "wait" (block)?

Tags: c++, opengl

Say I have a program that is really fast and, if vsync were disabled, would run >60fps. When does vsync force the program to wait? Does it block when you clear the screen or when you flip the buffers? Or is it some other time I'm not aware of?

I'm referring to OpenGL, incidentally.

---

**BONUS QUESTION**

Given there's not necessarily a specific point at which the blocking occurs, how would I measure how long the blocking is taking? In other words, how would I work out how fast the program *could* run?

Comment: vsync blocks front-back buffer swapping until next display sync signal. Clear and other drawing just draws to back buffer, which is not on screen [yet]

Comment: The effect is probably not visible from your code and will be handled by the graphics driver.

Comment: Most openGL commands are nonblocking.
The waiting for vsync is done when the buffer to which is drawn is swapped with the buffer to which is rendered. With glut this is done with the command `glutSwapBuffers()`, buth other libraries have other names for this function. GLFW has `glfwSwapBuffers(window)` for instance.

Comment: I don't believe GL exposes API to answer your bonus question. And even if it did, you can't just extrapolate this value and expect non-vsync framerate to match your estimate - because there are really a lot of factors affecting frame rate. But you can switch vsync on and off on the fly with (WGL|GLX)_EXT_swap_control extensions.

Comment: @keltar But unfortunately not on mobile. The problem is that on most mobile devices, vsync is forced on.

Comment: You can sort of solve your `BONUS QUESTION` if you work from the other end. Use a timer query for all the commands leading up to your swap, finish the query and then start a new one before the swap and finish it after. You will then have two times: frame time, and swap time. You can use them to infer a lot of things. Granted, you need a driver that supports timer queries, but that does not require any special hardware just an updated driver in most cases.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Hmm. Firstly, I don't know what a timer query is. I'd have to look that up, and it may be a little interesting to implement given I'm not using OpenGL directly (but have direct access to it). Secondly, the solution would need to work on any mobile device, since I intended it to be used in the end product on Google Play. Don't worry, though. I worked out a solution on my own. I just lowered the target fps of my code from 60fps to 50fps and used the extra 10fps to detect if the code could run faster. :)

Comment: Oh, well timer queries do not exist in OpenGL ES. For all intents and purposes on Stack Overflow, we distinguish between OpenGL and OpenGL ES because the differences between them are significant enough. They share a common base API (which roughly branched off around OpenGL 2.1 in the case of ES 2.0), but each one actually has some features that the other does not. Neither one is a strict subset of the other. Anyway, mobile devices run OpenGL ES.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Oh, ok, so I should have used OpenGL ES in the tags? Seems obvious in hind-sight - I'll remember that for next time :)

Comment: See also https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69305/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178326/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496298 https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69305/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comments to your answer show, that this remains still a topic with a lot of misconceptions.

To make a long story short: There is no explicit point at which your program will block.

The swap buffer call returns immediately. Don't believe me? Write a program that measures the time spent in one single swap buffers call (i.e. don't enter a rendering loop). But I hear you say: If I enable V-Sync and measure the frame rate in my program it shows the right frame rate, so somewhere it has to block.

Whats happening is, that after a call to swap buffers the back buffer is kind of "protected"; the back buffer is to be presented on the front buffer with the contents it had the the time of calling SwapBuffers. So the next operation that would alter the contents of the back buffer blocks after a call to SwapBuffers until the swap happened.

**BUT** (and that's a big but) the OpenGL command queue is asynchronous. What blocks is the execution of the command queue, but unless a synchronization point is inserted or the queue maximum capacity has reached all the OpenGL calls will return immediately. `glFinish` introduces a synchronization point. But if you place a glFinish right after a SwapBuffers, since it only acts on any drawing operation happening between itself and the previous SwapBuffers, there's nothing to finish yet and it will likely return immediately as well.

So you're in a rendering loop and measure the time of `SwapBuffers` there, and all of a sudden it takes one V-Sync interval to return. What's going on? Well, `SwapBuffers` implies a `glFlush`. But more importantly a buffer swap leaves the back buffer in an undefined state, which means, that a buffer swap operation is on the same level of buffer content modification as drawing commands. But because there are only two buffer (front and back) if there's already a buffer swap queued, the following one invokes a synchronization block until the previous swap has been performed. This stalls the command queue and ultimately makes one OpenGL drawing command or the SwapBuffers command block eventually.

Comment: Well, there is a good difference between GL swap buffer and drivers (or better - hardware) internal one. WGL/GLX/AGL SwapBuffers does not invoke glFinish but rather glFlush, and returns quickly. Driver is a different story - it delays buffer swap until drawing is complete and vsync interval is matched. In my observation in GL block happens in SwapBuffers when one buffer is already in wait queue, while application tries to submit another one - but this is not guaranteed (as, well, almost everything).

Comment: @keltar: Sorry, I meant to write `SwapBuffers` implies a `glFlush`; I fleshed out that part a bit as well.

Comment: @datenwolf Thanks, that helps greatly! What I'm trying to is measure the time that the program is blocking from vsync, so that I can calculate an approximate framerate that the program _could_ run at if vsync were disabled (trust me, I have a sensible reason for wanting to do this). Would you have any recommendations for this?

Comment: @Keltar: Actually, if you [disassemble `OpenGL32.dll`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QvDPj.png) as I have done for another similar question you will notice that the GDI path (right-hand side) invokes a full `glFinish (...)`; the ICD path (left-hand side) leaves the implementation up to the ICD. But that really should not be too surprising if you think about it, when you do rendering on the CPU the pipeline is already synchronized with ... the CPU so `glFinish (...)` is appropriate ;)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman thanks, interesting. But thats just one implementation, and documentation says of flush. On software implementation, I wouldn't be surprised if flush and finish is actually the same thing.

Comment: Rumors are that some vendors don't block on `glFinish()`.