# SDL2 and OpenGL, forcing FPS with Vsync disabled?

Tags: c++, opengl, frame-rate

I'm having an issue where some OpenGL functions seem to force my application to run 60fps. I'm using SDL2 and I specify

```
SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(0)
```

during initialization, which I thought disabled Vsync. For example, the following line of code will return 16 ms every time (Assuming it is the only code I run in the loop, if I have previously drawn something on-screen in a similar fashion it will take 16 ms to run that function instead and this one will be in the order of microseconds instead of milliseconds):

```
Uint32 begin = SDL_GetTicks();
GLint lightBuffer = glGetUniformLocation(cNight_shader.gProgramID, "lightBuffer");
GLint varying_time = glGetUniformLocation(cNight_shader.gProgramID, "varying_colour");
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColorBuffer);

glUseProgram(cNight_shader.gProgramID);
glUniform1i(lightBuffer, 2);
glUniform1f(varying_time, cNight_shader.f1);
draw_quad(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT); // (0, 0, myTexture);
glUseProgram(NULL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
Uint32 end = SDL_GetTicks();
std::cout << end - begin << std::endl;
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I'd also like to note that if I don't use any shaders or buffers and just do a simple:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
draw quad();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

This does not force the FPS, so I'm thinking the issue is related to my shaders, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you tried `SDL_SetHintWithPriority(...)`? [Here Reference](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetHintWithPriority). Before to create the renderer: `SDL_SetHintWithPriority(SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC, "0", SDL_HINT_OVERRIDE);`

Comment: @BiagioFesta: `SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC` is only for the SDL Renderer system, not OpenGL.

Comment: `glUseProgram(NULL);` <- Careful here, `NULL` doesn't always evaluate to integer 0 which the method expects.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not entirely sure why it was set to NULL there, every other time I've used it I've set it to 0. As to my actual problem it was a case of my own idiocy, my drivers were set to force vsync on. I got confused as I presumed vsync would force the delay when swapping buffers but obviously I was wrong, it seemed to force the delay the first time I try to draw something after swapping the buffers.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine: It will evaluate to integer 0 on any system that the OP is reasonably using.  The exceptions are arcane at best, and who knows if SDL runs on any such system.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, it turns out my drivers had set Vsync forced on which was causing this, and I was getting confused because I thought Vsync would only force a delay when swapping buffers, but that's clearly not the case, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135853/at-what-point-does-vsync-wait-block).